# How to calculate color coverage to a known color gamut?

Tags: python, colors

For example, I have a monitor that is capable of displaying the following basic RGB colors:

**data**: R(0.67, 0.32), G(0.28, 0.67), B(0.12, 0.07)

How can I calculate the color coverage of the monitor to a known gamut, such as the NTSC color space, using Python?

**NTSC**: R(0.67, 0.33), G(0.21, 0.71), B(0.14, 0.08)

I can use dedicated software to calculate this yielding 87.8%. But inputting the data into the software takes quite some time and I have a very long list of monitor RGB colors to work with. I wonder if there is some Python package that is capable of doing the calculation, and preferably outputting some image like below.

[image]

Comment: Note: the percentage you see (about coverage) are known to be bullshit, especially on the way you wrote it (and most people write it). Your are probably using a meaningless percent of CIE xyY (some people prefer CIELuv (but so you get different data). In short: convert data to chromacities (so x,y, as you already have), then you should calculate the intersection area of two triangles, and you divide by the area of the colour space triangle. So now you have a geometrical problem (and with triangles, so it should be easy).

Comment: Two things to remember: xy is good for colour mixing (and define chromaticities) but is it not perceptual, so the number may be good for computer but not for humans). And x,y is just a plane of all colours (also your figure). So you are not characterizing well the percentage of colour you can represent. So you may use to compare two additive RGB systems (and much care for the other systems).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thank you for your comment and advice. Yes exactly, CIELuv is supposed to be a more uniform color space (the geometric distance is about proportional to the color difference) than CIExy, though not perfect at all. However, it is still the common practice in the industry to use the color coverage in CIExy space to evaluate how a display is capable of reproducing all the colors.